# How to map database column names to Java class fields using apache-commons-dbutils

Tags: java, jdbc, apache-commons-dbutils

I would like to populate a POJO (State.java) from DB using `Apache DBUtils` library. However, since the names of the Bean properties do not match exactly with DB column names some of the properties are left unfilled.

Now, I did some research on this by googling and found that this can be achieved by:

1. Column aliasing while writing an SQL query (which I do not prefer as I have multiple joins in some of larger tables and hence would require lot of aliasing)
2. Using BeanProcessor (could not find a really good example anywhere)

Can anybody provide a good example on how to use `BeanProcessor` to map column names to properties? Tweaking the example provided me would be even better.

**DB Table**

```
CREATE TABLE public.states (
  state_id INTEGER DEFAULT nextval('states_seq'::regclass) NOT NULL,
  state_cd VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  tax_pct NUMERIC(10,2) DEFAULT 0.00 NOT NULL,
  active CHAR(1) DEFAULT 'Y'::bpchar NOT NULL,
)
```

**State.java**

```
  public class State implements Serializable {

    private int stateId;
    private String stateCode;
    private String name;
    private BigDecimal taxPct = new BigDecimal(0);
    private Date expiryDate;
    private String createdBy;
    private Date createdOn;
    private String active;

    //getters and setters here
}
```

**Main.java**

```
    public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String url = "jdbc:postgresql://gsi-547576.gsiccorp.net:5432/istore-db";
        String driver = "org.postgresql.Driver";
        String user = "postgres";
        String pwd = "postgres";
        Connection conn = null;
        List<State> states = null;

        try {
            DbUtils.loadDriver(driver);
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pwd);

            states = (List<State>) new QueryRunner().query(conn, "select * from states a where a.active='Y'", new BeanListHandler(State.class);

            System.out.println("states::  " + states);

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            DbUtils.closeQuietly(conn);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: See my answer. Had to do a lot of digging in the java docs and the source code to come up with a solution :)

Comment: Yes, bot I just did and getting `ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException`. See my updated code above.

Comment: That is not how stackoverflow works. You can't take an answer, add to your quesiton and keep creating new quesitons. If you got an issue with my answer, you can post a comment on my answer.

Comment: Apologize for this as I did not know how to show the changes that I did to my code to you and hence I edited the original question. The "Add Comment" section only allows me to add very little information.

Comment: No problem. But that's not how stackoverflow works. You can't just keep incrementing your question. You can post a new question instead of changing this question. I believe I have answered your original question `How to use BeanProcessor to map column names to properties`

Comment: Agreed and it is definitely a progress from earlier version of my program :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the Java docs for BeanProcessor :

> protected int[] mapColumnsToProperties(ResultSetMetaData rsmd,
>                              PropertyDescriptor[] props)
>                                   throws SQLException
>
> The positions in the returned array represent column numbers. The values stored at each
>   position represent the index in the PropertyDescriptor[] for the bean
>   property that matches the column name. If no bean property was found
>   for a column, the position is set to PROPERTY_NOT_FOUND. Parameters:
>   rsmd - The ResultSetMetaData containing column information. props -
>   The bean property descriptors. Returns: An int[] with column index to
>   property index mappings. The 0th element is meaningless because JDBC
>   column indexing starts at 1.

Looks like you will need to create a class that extends from `BeanProcessor` and overrides the `mapColumnsToProperties` method as follows :

```
public class StateBeanProcessor extends BeanProcessor {

    @Override
    protected  int[] mapColumnsToProperties(ResultSetMetaData rsmd, PropertyDescriptor[] props) throws SQLException {
          int[] mapping = super.mapColumnsToProperties(rsmd, props);
          /*Map database columns to fields in the order in which they appear
            1st column in the DB will be mapped to 1st field in the Java
            class and so on.. */
          for(int i=0;i<mapping.length;++i) {
             mapping[i]=i;
          }
      }
  }
```

You can then plugin the above StateBeanProcessor into your code as follows :

```
states = (List<State>) new QueryRunner().query(conn, "select * from states", new BeanListHandler(State.class,new BasicRowProcessor(new StateBeanProcessor())));
```

**Disclaimer :** I have not tested out this code. It aims to show you the bits and pieces that you can put together to have custom field mappings. If you find an issue with it, you can let me know so I can look into it.

Comment: Really appreciate bot for so much of research on this. However, I tried your code and i am getting `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 9`. I have updated my original code base for your reference. I has something to do with mapping but not sure how as I still cannot visualize the whole picture here.

Comment: You should NOT copy someone elses answer into your question and make a new question out of it. I have edited the answer to fix your problem.

Comment: After trying your latest answer now getting following exception: `java.sql.SQLException: Cannot set createdOn: incompatible types, cannot convert java.lang.String to java.util.Date Query: select * from states a where a.active='Y' Parameters: []
 at org.apache.commons.dbutils.AbstractQueryRunner.rethrow(AbstractQueryRunner.java:392)`

Answer (score 7):

```
Map<String,String> mapColumnsToProperties = new HashMap<>();
//mapping you database to entity here;
mapColumnsToProperties.put("database_column","entity_property");
BeanProcessor beanProcessor = new BeanProcessor(mapColumnsToProperties);
RowProcessor rowProcessor = new BasicRowProcessor( beanProcessor); 
ResultSetHandler<List<Entity>> resultSetHandler = new BeanListHandler<Entity>(Entity.class,rowProcessor);
List<Entity> entityLists = queryRunner.query(findListSQL, resultSetHandler);
```

Comment: You should explain your answer.

Comment: sorry ，I'm Chinese,My English is poor,I think you just need to get the key words.just use hashMap to convert column name to bean  property.You can click here https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbutils/examples.html

Answer (score 2):

i'm from china,my english is not very well;
but this issue ,this is my resolve :
because the dbutils is open source, you can modify the source code, and use maven to make a jar only for you ,i just modify the BeanProcessor class,you can add a method named `changeColumnName` like this :

```
public  String changeColumnName(String columnName){
        if(columnName == null){
            return null;
        }
        if(columnName.contains("_")){
            char[] cs = columnName.toCharArray();
            int flag = -1;
            for(int index=0;index<columnName.toCharArray().length;index++){
                if(cs[index] == '_'){
                    flag = index;
                    break;
                }
            }
            columnName = columnName.substring(0, flag) + columnName.substring(flag+1,flag+2).toUpperCase() + columnName.substring(flag+2);
            return changeColumnName(columnName);
        }else{
            return columnName;
        }
    }
```

and  in the method

```
protected int[] mapColumnsToProperties(ResultSetMetaData rsmd,
        PropertyDescriptor[] props) throws SQLException {

    int cols = rsmd.getColumnCount();
    int[] columnToProperty = new int[cols + 1];
    Arrays.fill(columnToProperty, PROPERTY_NOT_FOUND);

    for (int col = 1; col <= cols; col++) {
        String columnName = rsmd.getColumnLabel(col);
        if (null == columnName || 0 == columnName.length()) {
          columnName = rsmd.getColumnName(col);
        }
        String propertyName = columnToPropertyOverrides.get(columnName);
        if (propertyName == null) {
            propertyName = changeColumnName(columnName);//add here
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < props.length; i++) {

            if (propertyName.equalsIgnoreCase(props[i].getName())) {
                columnToProperty[col] = i;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return columnToProperty;
}
```

it can solve the problem.welcome to discuss with me .my google email is guomin.bai@gmail.com

Answer (score 2):

I have already answered similar [so question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24563564/dbutils-fails-to-fill-fields-of-a-java-bean/47173835#47173835).

You can use `GenerousBeanProcessor` which is a subclass of `BeanProcessor` it ignores underscore & case sensitivity from column name. You don't have to implement your own custom `BeanProcessor` for this particular case.

`GenerousBeanProcessor` is available since version 1.6 of *commons-dbutils*.

Usage:

```
// TODO initialize
QueryRunner queryRunner = null;

ResultSetHandler<List<State>> resultSetHandler =
                new BeanListHandler<State>(State.class, new BasicRowProcessor(new GenerousBeanProcessor()));

// best practice is mentioning only required columns in the query
final List<State> states = queryRunner.query("select * from states a where a.active='Y'", resultSetHandler);

for (State state : states) {
    System.out.println(state.getStateId());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily done using MapListHandler and Jackson without defining a custom bean processor or providing a column mapping.

1. change your POJO to

   ```
    public class State implements Serializable {

    @JsonProperty("state_id")//db column name
    private int stateId;

    @JsonProperty("state_cd")
    private String stateCode;

    //and so on ....
   ```

   }
2. Use MapListHandler with Jackson to fetch and convert the response to POJO.

```java
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

List<State> stateList = new QueryRunner()
.query(connection, query, new MapListHandler())
.stream()
.map(response -> objectMapper.convertValue(response, State.class))
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

In this approach, you are first fetching List<Map<String, Object>> which is a list of records and each record is coming in a map of column name and value, which can be mapped to a POJO using Jackson's convertValue method (which will use @JsonProperty annotation to map the column to the POJO field).

This approach will give you better control of mapping a DB column to a POJO field.